# Pandas: Add new columns based on others columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame like this:

```
>>>df
  paper year citation
0   A   2000    1
1   A   2001    2
2   B   2000    3
3   B   2001    4
4   B   2002    5
```

I want to add three columns (i.e. year2000, year2001, year2002), so the result would be:

```
>>>dfnew
  paper year2000 year2001 year2002
0   A      1        2         0
1   B      3        4         5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pivot_table` with `values='citation'`, `rows='paper'`, `columns='year'` and fill `NaNs` via `fill_value=0`

```
In [9]: pd.pivot_table(df, values='citation', rows='paper', columns='year', fill_value=0)
Out[9]:
year   2000  2001  2002
paper
A         1     2     0
B         3     4     5
```

Alternatively, you could use `pd.crosstab` like

```
In [10]: pd.crosstab(index=df['paper'], columns=df['year'], values=df['citation'],
                     aggfunc=pd.np.sum)
Out[15]:
year   2000  2001  2002
paper
A         1     2   NaN
B         3     4     5
```